# Merge [p4] and [perforce] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The title says it all. [p4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/p4) has been used to either tag a question regarding the [perforce](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/perforce) revision control system or, in [one case](https://serverfault.com/questions/110279/is-disk-dying-weird-numbers-on-iostat), to indicate a hardware platform. As [p4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/p4) was less widely used, apparently ambiguous and referring to the command line client utility of the perforce suite only, I have removed / replaced this tag from questions using it, so it should be merged into [perforce](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/perforce)

Comment: my, the line spacing looks crappy due to the tag references.

Comment: Address all aesthetic complaints to the Monsanto corporation! (Because I'm sure Jin is sick of our bitching by now :-)

Comment: If he's sick of the bitching maybe it's time something was done to rectify the issues and thereby remove the need to bitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[p4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/p4) --> [perforce](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/perforce) created.